# Refresh page (browser button) leads to save item to database again

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Situation:

- imagine one form for adding items to the database
- user correctly fill the form and using **Save** button (h:commandButton) save the item into the DTB
- lifecycle of saved object is finished and form is cleared
- after that, user (don't ask me why:-)) press the refresh button of the browser
- and result is => there are two almost the same items in the DTB (different just in create time)

How can I prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use ajax to execute the action (this doesn't generate browser history).

   ```
   <h:commandButton ...>
       <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```
2. Send a redirect after post (known as POST-Redirect-GET pattern).

   ```
   public String save() {
       // ...
       return "sameview?faces-redirect=true";
   }
   ```

Comment: I've tried it immediatelly and the second way works for me (the first one doesn't because it's mixed with another implemented ajax function)! Could you tell me what I've did? Why the redirect solved my problem?

Comment: A redirect basically instructs the webbrowser to send a new GET request on the given URL. The F5 would then refresh the redirected GET request, not the initial POST request.

Comment: Ajaj, I'm sorry, I've made a ridiculous mistake and looked somewhere else, and it didnt't helped. I have to keep this ticket open for now and try to continue later :-) Anyway, thank you

Comment: It works now, but unfortunately, it is unusable form be, because the whole view is reloaded and therefor cleared...

Comment: Yes, that's indeed how it works. I'm not sure how that's a problem as that's the usual practice and you also have mentioned "and form is cleared" yourself. In any way, go for the ajax option then.

Comment: I thought partially cleaned :D There must remain couple of information in the form after save to be user friendly :-) Anyway, the ajax call seems to be working, so I'll try this way..

Comment: Ajax call is bombastic! It works perfectly and also faster without page reloading. Is it entirely safe (regarding jsf lifecycle - in my opinion it is, lifecycle is really completed)?